# convertion of arabic text to iso-8859-6 format

Tags: c#, iso-8859-1

when I sending arabic text over url in browser I am getting that text as 
`%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81%20%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83`

> Eg: كيف حالك to %D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81%20%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83

I browsed in google I got answers like it is converted to `UTF-8 iso-8859-6` format. I am new to this encoding stuff. I want to store this convertion in database

how to achieve this encoding which was done by browser using c#?

Comment: Should be a bit obvious by now that you are looking for HttpUtility.UrlEncode().  Why are you not using it??

Comment: ok. I got it. Thanks a lot. I can use this method in all kinds of application. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do url encode/decode.

Try using this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Have you tried HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode or HttpUtility.UrlDecode?

Comment: thanks for the reply and I have come to know the decoding process of the url, but I want to encode the arabic text as it was done by browser. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

This a sample how you can decode your URL

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{       
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string returnUrl = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["url"]);
        ReturnPage.NavigateUrl = returnUrl;
    }
}
```

[MSDN](http://HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode%20Method%20(String))

Comment: thanks for the reply and I have come to know another decoding process of the url, but I want to encode the arabic text as it was done by browser. Sorry that I am not clear with my question.